# Facebook connect ifUserConnected() does not work - FB.Connect is undefined error

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to integrate Facebook connect to my website. The login button appears and i'm able to login. The profile picture and the name is displayed properly. However when I try adding the code FB.Connect.ifUserConnected, I get a error message saying FB.Connect is not defined.

This is what I'm doing

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({ appId: 'my app id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
</script>

<fb:login-button onlogin="fb_login()"></fb:login-button>

<script>
function fb_login() {
    $("#SocialConnectButtons").hide();
    $("#UserProfile").show();
    FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomTree();
}
//ALL UNTIL HERE WORKS AS EXPECTED, BUT THE FOLLOWING LINE FAILS
FB.Connect.ifUserConnected(fb_login);
</script>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the new Graph API (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js)

The code you wrote will not work. Check the Graph API javascript SDK here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

and for the API itself:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 2):

**[Here is a good tutorial to get started with new API for facebook connect.](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-javascript-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/)**

Comment: Thanks Sarfraz, but doesn't answer my question